# Ex.1.1 9 from topology without tears

Tags: general-topology

[image]

this question says only three of the below are topology.

So,according to me,$\tau_2$ is topology it is satisfying all three definition for topology.

And I believe $\tau$ consisting of $\mathbb{R}$,$\phi$ and  every interval $[-r,r]$,for $r$ any positive real number is also a topology.So $\tau_9$ is union of both $\tau$ and $\tau_2$ with $\tau_2 \subset \tau$ so is also a topology.

Similarly $\tau_0$ consisting of $\mathbb{R},\phi$ and every interval $[-n,n]$,for $n$ any positive integer is also topology.So $\tau_{10}$ is union of both the topology with one containing the other so is also a topology.

so i think $\tau_2$,$\tau_9$ and $\tau_{10}$ are the required topology,am i correct?

And I also want to know whether $\tau_7$ and $\tau_8$ are topology or not with justification.

Comment: $\tau=\tau_4$ is not a topology. It is not closed under arbitrary unions of open subsets; similarly $\tau_7$ and $\tau_8$. The union of topologies need not be a topology. $\tau_9$ however is still a topology, not for the stated reason.

Comment: The typical example of arbitrary union that makes $[-r,r]$ for $r$ real, $7$ and $8$ not a topology are $r$ approximating a particular number from the "closed" part of the interval. For example, the sequence $r_n = 2-1/n$. The union with this $r$ is exactly $(-2,2)$ in the three examples, but that interval is in neither of them, so they can't be a topology.

Comment: I know union of topology need not be  topology but i read if one of the topology is contained in other then the union is also topology.Am i correct?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. $\tau_1$ is **not** a topology since $(a,b)\cup(c,d) \notin \tau_1$ where $a<b<c<d$.

---

2. $\tau_2$ is a topology ($\checkmark$)  since  $$\bigcup_{i\in I}(-r_i,r_i) =\begin{cases} (-R,R) & I \text{ is finite} \land R = \max\{r_i \mid i \in I\} \\ \mathbb R & I \text{ is not finite} \end{cases}$$  and $$\bigcap_{i\in J}(-r_i,r_i) = (-r,r)$$ where $r = \min\{r_i \mid i \in J\}$ ($J$ is finite).

---

3. $\tau_3$ is **not** a topology since for some irrational $a$ we have
   $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-r_n,r_n) = (-a,a)\notin \tau_3$$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n = a$.

---

4. $\tau_4$ is **not** a topology since $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[-r_n+\frac 1n,r_n-\frac 1n\right] = (-r,r)\notin \tau_4$$

---

5. $\tau_5$ is **not** a topology for a similar reason as 3.

---

6. $\tau_6$ is **not** a topology for a similar reason as 4 (note that if $a$ is irrational then so is $a + \frac{1}{n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$).

---

7. $\tau_7$ is **not** a topology for a similar reason as 4.

---

8. $\tau_8$ is **not** a topology for a similar reason as 4.

---

9. $\tau_9$ is a topology ($\checkmark$) since one cannot use the "trick" that was used in 4. (try to show it rigorously)

---

10. $\tau_{10}$ is a topology ($\checkmark$) since one cannot use the "trick" that was used in 4. (try to show it rigorously)

Comment: In $\tau_4$ I think you meant $[-r+\frac{1}{n}, r-\frac{1}{n}]$

Comment: @ACheca Exactly! Thank you.

Comment: Hello,
@VIVID can you explain to me why the fact that one cannot use the trick from 4, proves 9 and 10? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @artobjective (9) since the intervals are symmetric about the origin, infinite union be either both-open eneded or both-closed ended intervals, which are again in $\tau_9$. (10) Infinite union of $[-n, n]$ and/or $(-r, r)$ is again in the form of either of them.