# Topology without Tears Chapter 1, Question #9: Topology of (a,b) for any real number, a < b

Tags: general-topology

This is the relevant parts of the question:

i) Let R be the set of all real numbers. 1 consists of R, ∅, and every interval (a,b) for a and b any real numbers a < b.

This questioned was answered here:
[Ex.1.1 9 from topology without tears](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976174/ex-1-1-9-from-topology-without-tears)

Answer:
1 is not a topology since (,)∪(,)∉1 where <<<.

But I do not understand how this is not a topology (as answered in the question). If a,b can any real number, then why can't I find a (b,c)∈ 1 as long as b < c? If I understand the question correctly, we are creating open covers throughout the whole real number line. Is this correct? If so, then there shouldn't be any gaps? Numerically, this is how I envisioned this. Let a = 1, b =5, c =7, d = 9.

If (a,b) = (1,5) and and (c,d) = (7,9), then there is nothing stopping me from also selecting (1,9) and (5,7) to cover the entire number line since 1 < 9 and 5 < 7. I can do this for any arbitrary a,b,c,d.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. If it is stipulated to contain open intervals but not their union, it’s not a topology

Comment: Thank you! Is the question saying that there is only three elements in 1: R, ∅ and (a,b)?

Comment: There are uncountably many elements because $a$ could be any real number

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that each of the following is in $\tau_1$: $(1,5),(7,9),(1,9),(5,7).$

In fact, for any $x$ on the real line, there exist $a,b$ with $a<b$ such that $x\in(a,b)\in\tau_1.$ This means that $\tau_1$ is a cover of the real line. In fact, $\tau_1$ is a subbasis, and even a basis, for the usual topology on the real line.

However, since unions of elements of $\tau_1$ need not be elements of $\tau_1,$ themselves--for example, $(1,5)\cup(7,9)$ is not an element of $\tau_1$--then $\tau_1$ is not, itself, a topology.

Put another way, every topology is a cover of the underlying set, but the converse may not hold--consider any non-empty set $X$, and note that $\{X\}$ is a cover, but not a topology.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still not sure why their union wouldn't be an element 1, since the question says "every interval." Doesn't every interval imply that unions are involved? Or is the question saying that 1 consists of only one interval?

Edit: For the example you provided, couldn't I add the interval (5,7) to 1?

Comment: $\tau1$ has all intervals, but $(a,b)\cup(c,d)$ where $a<b<c<d$ is not an interval

Comment: @KevinSterling, you don't *need* to add the interval $(5,7)$ to $\tau_1.$ As I mentioned, $(5,7)$ is an element of $\tau_1.$ However, $(1,5)\cup(7,9)$ is not an element of $\tau_1,$ because the elements $U$ of $\tau_1$ are exactly $\emptyset,$ $\Bbb R,$ and the sets $U$ for which there exist unique real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$ such that $$U=\{x\in\Bbb R:a<x<b\}.$$ You can show that and $(1,5)\cup(7,9)$ has none of these three forms--that is, it's not empty, it's not all of $\Bbb R,$ and there exist no real $a$ and $b$ such that $$(1,5)\cup(7,9)=\{x\in\Bbb R:a<x<b\}.$$

Comment: One way to prove it in a straightforward fashion is this: show that the elements $U$ of $\tau_1$ all have the property that if $c$ and $d$ are in $U,$ and if $x$ is a real number with $c<x<d,$ then $x\in U.$ However, $(1,5)\cup(7,9)$ does not have this property. (Can you see why?) Thus, $(1,5)\cup(7,9)$ is not an element of $\tau_1.$

Comment: I guess where I am getting tripped up is what it means for a union of intervals. I keep saying to "add" (5,7) so that we have (1,5) ∪ (5,7) ∪ (7,9). So (1,5) ∪ (5,7) ∪ (7,9)≠(1,9)? I just don't clearly see why (1,5) ∪ (5,7) ∪ (7,9)≠(1,9).

Comment: $(1,9)$ has $7$, but that union of open intervals does not

Comment: I’m not clear why it doesn’t. If we can choose any a< b ?

Comment: You think $7\in(1,5)\cup(5,7)\cup(6,8)$??

Comment: @KevinSterling, **some** unions of open intervals will be elements of $\tau_1.$ For example, $(1,5)\cup(4,8)\cup(7,9)\in\tau_1.$ That is not enough to make it a topology, though; we need ***every*** union for that. Please try what I suggested: show that every element $U$ of $\tau_1$ has this property: if $c,d\in U$ and $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $c<x<d,$ then $x\in U.$ Subsets $U$ of $\Bbb R$ with this property are called *connected*. Then, show that $(1,5)\cup(7,9)$ is **not** connected.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I think you meant to type $(7,9)$ instead of $(6,8),$ there.

Comment: Yes, @CameronBuie, that's what I meant