# Topology Without Tears Exercise $1.1.9$ - Union of infinite rational open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm working through the book Topology without Tears by Sidney A. Morris, and I've come to a roadblock while trying to solve exercise $1.1.9$, specifically with part iii. My background is primarily in mechanical and software engineering, and am not yet very comfortable with pure mathematics and set theory, but I'm hoping to get there.

The problem is stated as:
"*Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of all real numbers. Precisely three of the following ten collections of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are topologies? Identify these and justify your answer*".

It then continues to list 8 different sets that could potentially be topologies in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm specifically concerned with the third one being listed:

*$\tau_3$ consists of $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset$*, and every interval $(-r,r)$, for $r$ any positive rational number.

My intuition tells me that this should be a topology. After all, any pair of positive rational numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ must be such that either $r_1>r_2$, $r_1<r_2$, or $r_1=r_2$. In any case, the intervals $(-r,r)$ formed by $r_1$ and $r_2$ would result in one interval being a subset of the other. Meaning that the union of the two intervals would simply be the larger of the two intervals and thus remain an open set, and the intersection of the two intervals would simply be the smaller of the two intervals and thus remain an open set.

However, context clues (following this same logic results in way more than 3 valid topologies), and a broader but very similar question: [Ex.1.1 9 from topology without tears](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976174/ex-1-1-9-from-topology-without-tears?newreg=52c6b1b63f984dd585362c36c4e29a60) suggests that my logic is flawed.

Looking through the answer to the question linked above, the explanation for why this was not a topology is as follows:

"$\tau_3$ is **not** a topology since for some irrational $a$ we have
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-r_n,r_n) = (-a,a)\notin \tau_3$$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n = a$."

I don't follow this explanation. Why would an infinite union of these rational open intervals become an irrational open interval? Why would it not just be some infinitely large rational open interval? I feel like this alludes to some key piece of information that I'm missing that would likely be very helpful for me throughout the rest of this book.

Comment: The union of such intervals need not have rational endpoints, so it can't be open.  Done.  Think about approximating $\sqrt{2}$ by rational numbers.

Comment: @Randall Yeah that seems to be the gist of the referenced answer as well. But my problem is that I just don't see why that would be the case. Why would it ever not have rational endpoints? Any one of these intervals would either be a subset of another or vice versa, correct? So the union of any number of these intervals would just be the largest of these intervals, all of which have rational endpoints. Am I missing something?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: What you are missing is that there is no "largest" when the union is infinite.  "Largest" will only make sense for a finite collection.  You would be correct if the union axiom only applied to finite collections.  (In the same way that a finite decimal must be rational.)  It's akin to asking "what is the smallest number among 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc.?"  There isn't one.

Comment: You and Kyle  both make the point that the infinite expansion of decimals may result in an irrational number in your answers. That in itself makes sense to me. However, I don't see how this necessarily applies to the problem as stated. The presented set is defined as containing: **every interval (−,), for  any positive rational number**. This suggests to me, that the moment you're considering some infinite expansion of decimal places such that $r$ is now irrational, then r is obviously not a positive rational number, and thus is not in the set.

Comment: It doesn't matter that there's no largest positive rational number, but there is always a **larger** rational number, and thus a rational interval that fully encompasses the previous.

Comment: You are not understanding the definitions correctly.

Comment: No, probably not. But which definition in particular?

Comment: You seem to think that the irrational number $a$ is being included in the topology somehow (and it shouldn't be) or that we are not allowed to make arguments using irrational numbers if your definition references only rational numbers.  The question is:  is it true that for ALL possible collections of rational-ends intervals that their union is ALWAYS a rational-end interval?  And the answer to that question is no by the construct in my answer.

Comment: I wonder now if the issue is understanding the purely logical structure of the argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the decimal expansion of an irrational number $a$:
$$
a = a_0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots 
$$
Let $r_i$ be the expression above truncated to the $i$th decimal place.  So, $r_1=a_0.a_1$, $r_2=a_0.a_1a_2$, etc.  Each $r_i$ is rational.  Checking definitions shows that
$$
(-a,a) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (-r_i,r_i).
$$
But this cannot be open since $a$ is irrational.

Comment: Just one possibly unimportant question for my clarification. Does the fact that it's an *infinite union* have any significance? Would your argument be the same just considering some $r = a_0.a_1a_2a_3...a_i$ with $i$ continually increasing to infinity? Though in this case, this $r$ would be irrational, and thus not be a part of this infinite union in the first place.

Your explanations allude to some significance to the fact that they're being union'ed. But I don't see it. With my current understanding, you can just consider the one case where $i=\inf$ and that would result in the same set.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, it REALLY matters that the union axiom must also apply to infinite unions.  But what does $i = inf$ mean?  [That's why I think you're misunderstanding what a union really is.]

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write $r=a_0.a_1a_2 \cdots a_i$ with $i$ increasing to infinity, since when you change $i$ you are presumably also changing $r$, which is a constant number.

Comment: Fair. My notation is off then. But the point is that you're presenting some infinite union of rational intervals. And that when you consider this infinite union, there is a point at which $r_i=a$. At least that's how I've interpreted it. At that point, all previous intervals that had been included in the union are pointless, because when $r_i=a$, all other intervals are just a subset of this final interval. (I feel like you're going to criticize me for the use of "final", but what I mean is when $r_i$ is finally equal to $a$).

Comment: Like you've put together a for-loop, but only need to do any work during the final iteration. Since if $A\subseteq B$, then $A\cup B = B$.

Comment: OK, but please notice that once again you're talking about $A \cup B$, which is a union with a FINITE number of terms ;)

Comment: @jdong-sw "And that when you consider this infinite union, there is a point at which $r_i=a$."  No.  At that supposed point, $r_i=a_0.a_1a_2a_3...a_i$, so it is less than $a$ by $0.000...0a_{i+1}a_{i+2}...$.  No matter what finite $i$ you stop at, $r_i$ is still less than $a$.

Comment: It does still seem to me as if this union operation is just being used as a mechanism to consider some $r_i$ where $i$ is infinity. And that the actual union-ing of the individual terms has no contribution because each subsequent union $r_{i+1}$ makes all previous considered terms $r_{i}, r_{i-1},...$ meaningless. But I'll chalk that up to me needing to reinforce my foundation on set theory, limits, etc.

Comment: However, I grant that the question is answered. You've provided enough additional explanation about the presented answer from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976174/ex-1-1-9-from-topology-without-tears?newreg=52c6b1b63f984dd585362c36c4e29a60 that I now understand the general idea being proposed. And if I take for granted that this infinite expansion of decimal places of rational numbers can become equivalent to an irrational number, without technically being irrational and thus violating the definition of $\tau_3$, then the answer does make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have some background in software, think about how a computer might represent/approximate an irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$. It doesn't have infinitely many digits to work with, so it cuts it off somewhere, giving a "rational" (floating point) approximation. But now imagine that you have a computer with more power—such a computer could increase the number of bits in the representation, giving a "better" approximation to $\sqrt{2}$. It's still a rational/floating point approximation, but it's closer than the first one.

Now, consider a sequence of "better and better" computers, giving "better and better" rational approximations. Each computer can only give a rational approximation, but in the "limit" you get the irrational number $\sqrt{2}$. This limiting sequence is what the sequence of $r_n$'s might represent when we're looking, for example, at $a = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Kyle I can follow that in the limit you get an irrational number. But a number can only either be rational or irrational. If in the limit, this representation becomes a valid irrational number, then, well it's an irrational number and thus does not correspond to a rational interval contained within $\tau_3$ by definition of $\tau_3$.